# udp binded/connected but not datagram received

Tags: qt, udpclient

I am new to Qt, c++, recently I am trying to use UDP to receive data on my raspberrypi1 from another raspberrypi2 (multicast). I am able to bind both of them but I can't receive the data (nopendingdatagram). I wonder what I did wrong here. (As you might notice, the code below was taken from examples found online). Thank you in advanced for helping me.

```
// myudp.h

#ifndef MYUDP_H
#define MYUDP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>

class MyUDP : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit MyUDP(QObject *parent = 0);
   //void HelloUDP();
signals:

public slots:
   void readyRead();

private:
   QUdpSocket *socket;

};

#endif // MYUDP_H
```

```
// myudp.cpp

#include "myudp.h"

MyUDP::MyUDP(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    // create a QUDP socket
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);

    bool result = socket->bind(QHostAddress("224.224.0.2"), 10002);
    
    if(result)
    {
        qDebug() << "Socket Connected";
    }
                    
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Socket Not Connected";           
    }
                    
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

void MyUDP::readyRead()
{
    // when data comes in
    bool data_pending = socket->hasPendingDatagrams();
    qDebug() << data_pending;
    
    if(data_pending)
    {
        QByteArray buffer;
        buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
    
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;
    
        socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(),
                             &sender, &senderPort);
    
        qDebug() << "Message from: " << sender.toString();
        qDebug() << "Message port: " << senderPort;
        qDebug() << "Message: " << buffer;
    }
    
    else 
    {
        qDebug() << "No data";
    }
    
}
```

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myudp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyUDP client;

    client.readyRead();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
Socket Connected
false
No data
```

Comment: You must not call readyRead() by yourself but wait until data arrives. See the examples here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#details

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have changed the line connect(socket.... ) and the readyRead() function to match the examples. Still, it is not showing me the output that I want. I am running wireshark at the same time and it is receiving the datagram. As such, I am trying to visualize what I am seeing on wireshark, on Qt.

Comment: I have found a solution. Apparently raspberry could not receive directly the multicast. As such, the problem could be fixed by channeling the multicast address on the network tram to local host on the raspberry.